# Condition number after preconditioning

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Suppose $A$ and $P$ are symmetric, positive definite matrices and that we factor $P^{-1}=EE^\top.$  Is it true that the condition number of $PA$ is upper-bounded by the condition number of $E^{-1}AE^{-\top}$?

The two matrices clearly have the same eigenvalues, but $PA$ may not be symmetric.  So, I wasn't sure if this still implies that they have the same singular values.

[Apologies if this is a goofy question!  Just a potential hole in a proof of preconditioning for conjugate gradients...]

REVISION:  The two matrices do not have the same singular values, but numerically it appears $\mathrm{cond}\ PA\geq\mathrm{cond}\ E^{-1}AE^{-\top}.$  I'm totally stuck how to prove this!

Comment: I understand!  In this case, I know that $PA$ and $E^{-1}A E^{-\top}$ have the same eigenvalues.  Am I missing an obvious argument that applies the definition you mention to showing that they have the same singular values?

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do :-)

In other words, we're comparing the eigenvalues of $PAAP$ and $E^{-1}APAE^{-\top}$.  These are not obviously the same to me -- but I'm operating on very little sleep at the moment!  A student asked about this and I'm embarrassed I'm stumped :-)

Comment: Oh, sorry to have given obvious pointers. I agree that that it does not follow that the SVs are the same.

Comment: Updated a bit.  The two matrices don't have the same singular values, but the condition number statement appears to be true.  Totally stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\kappa(E^{-1}AE^{-T}) \le \kappa(PA)$. For any matrix $X$, $|\lambda| \le \Vert X \Vert$ holds for any eigenvalue and any induced norm (since $\Vert \lambda u \Vert$ = $\Vert X u \Vert \le \Vert X \Vert \Vert u \Vert$ for the eigenvector $u$). Similarly, if $X$ is invertible, then $|\lambda^{-1}| \le \Vert X^{-1} \Vert$ for any eigenvalue. Now take $X = PA$ and apply these inequalities with the largest and smallest eigenvalues. Multiplying, we see that
$$ \kappa( E^{-1}AE^{-T} ) = |\lambda_{\text{max}}|/|\lambda_{\text{min}}| \le \Vert PA \Vert \Vert (PA)^{-1} \Vert = \kappa( PA ) . $$

Comment: Of course!  Thank you so much -- this has been driving me nuts.